# What name of generated database by liferay?

Tags: java, postgresql, liferay

Where are tables that generated database by Liferay through service.xml?. I don't see it in my Postgres. There are so many tables, I tried to find it but it not found. Anyone can help me, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you explicitly specify the table name in the entities that you declare in service.xml, the table names are constructed with the namespace and entity name.

```
<service-builder package-path="com.liferay.docs.guestbook">
    <namespace>GB</namespace>
    <entity name="Guestbook" local-service="true" uuid="true">
    ...
```

would generate `GB_Guestbook` as table name.

From the [very well documented DTD](https://docs.liferay.com/dxp/portal/7.1-latest/definitions/liferay-service-builder_7_1_0.dtd.html):

> `<namespace>`
>
> The namespace element must be a unique namespace for this component.
>   Table names will be prepended with this namespace. Generated JSON
>   JavaScript will be scoped to this namespace as well (i.e.,
>   Liferay.Service.Test.* if the namespace is Test).
>
> `<entity>`    Child of service-builder
>
> An entity usually represents a business facade and a table in the
>   database. If an entity does not have any columns, then it only
>   represents a business facade. The Service Builder will always generate
>   an empty business facade POJO if it does not exist. Upon subsequent
>   generations, the Service Builder will check to see if the business
>   facade already exists. If it exists and has additional methods, then
>   the Service Builder will also update the SOAP wrappers.
>
> If an entity does have columns, then the value object, the POJO class
>   that is mapped to the database, and other persistence utilities are
>   also generated based on the order and finder elements.
>
> ...

(and you'll find more hints, e.g. explicit table names, in that document)

Notes:

- If you declare that the entities are stored in an external (non-Liferay) datasource, no tables will be created.
- Also, some versions of Liferay automatically updated the database structure on deployment of a new plugin version (with updated persistence layers), while others don't do this automatically (it's a developer feature anyways, not good for large - production - amount of data)